# GridBagLayout Table

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

I am trying to make a table with GridBagLayout, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * Created by 20114283 on 8/21/2016.
 */
public class TableGrid extends JFrame{

    JPanel p;
    JTextField title;
    JTextField t01;
    JTextField t02;
    JTextField t03;
    JTextField t04;
    JTextField t05;
    JTextField t11;
    JTextField t12;
    JTextField t13;
    JTextField t14;
    JTextField t15;
    JTextField t21;
    JTextField t22;
    JTextField t23;
    JTextField t24;
    JTextField t25;
    JTextField t31;
    JTextField t32;
    JTextField t33;
    JTextField t34;
    JTextField t35;

    public TableGrid(){
        createView();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Table");
        setSize(new Dimension(700,370));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    private void createView(){

        GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
        layout.columnWidths = new int[] {140,200,180,180};
        layout.rowHeights = new int[] {80,100,50,50,50,50};
        p = new JPanel(layout);
        this.getContentPane().add(p);

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 4;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        p.add(title = new JTextField("Cooking Club Members Scores"));

        //column 1
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        p.add(t01 = new JTextField(""));

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        p.add(t02 = new JTextField("Beth"));

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        p.add(t03 = new JTextField("Jon"));

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        p.add(t04 = new JTextField("Lupe"));

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 5;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        p.add(t05 = new JTextField("Amy"));

        //column 2

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        p.add(t11 = new JTextField("Appetizer"));

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        p.add(t12 = new JTextField("25"));

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        p.add(t13 = new JTextField("35"));

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        p.add(t14 = new JTextField("20"));

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 5;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        p.add(t15 = new JTextField("40"));


        //column 3

        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        p.add(t21 = new JTextField("Main Course"));

        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        p.add(t22 = new JTextField("38"));

        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        p.add(t23 = new JTextField("29"));

        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        p.add(t24 = new JTextField("31"));


        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 5;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        p.add(t25 = new JTextField("32"));

        //column 4

        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        p.add(t31 = new JTextField("Dessert"));

        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        p.add(t32 = new JTextField("28"));

        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        p.add(t33 = new JTextField("37"));

        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        p.add(t34 = new JTextField("39"));

        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 5;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        p.add(t35 = new JTextField("36"));


    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new TableGrid();
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Repeating "Please help" at the end of your question is not useful. Saying precisely what you're trying to do, what results you're getting, and how those aren't the results you want is useful. Please also take the time to use the preview that the site showed you, and the various formatting tools.

Answer (score 0):

I heavily modified your code to create this GUI.

[image: Table GUI]

Here are the changes I made to your code.

1. I added a call to the SwingUtilities invokeLater method in your main method.  The invokeLater method puts the creation and usage of the Swing components on the Event Dispatch thread.  Oracle and I insist that you start all Swing applications on the Event Dispatch thread.
2. I used a JFrame.  I did not extend a JFrame.  The only reason you would extend a Swing component, or any Java class, is if you want to override one or more of the class methods.
3. I rearranged the JFrame method calls to their proper order.  Tje JFrame methods must be called in this order.
4. When creating a GridBagLayout, you arrange the Swing components in rows, not columns.
5. When adding a Swing component to a GridBagLayout, you have to add the GridBagConstraints to the add method.

Here's the corrected code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 * Created by 20114283 on 8/21/2016.
 */
public class TableGrid implements Runnable {

    JFrame frame;

    JTextField title;
    JTextField t01;
    JTextField t02;
    JTextField t03;
    JTextField t04;
    JTextField t05;
    JTextField t11;
    JTextField t12;
    JTextField t13;
    JTextField t14;
    JTextField t15;
    JTextField t21;
    JTextField t22;
    JTextField t23;
    JTextField t24;
    JTextField t25;
    JTextField t31;
    JTextField t32;
    JTextField t33;
    JTextField t34;
    JTextField t35;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Table");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createView());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createView() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 4;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        panel.add(title = new JTextField("Cooking Club Members Scores"), c);

        // row 1
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(t01 = new JTextField(" "), c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(t11 = new JTextField("Appetizer"), c);

        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(t21 = new JTextField("Main Course"), c);

        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(t31 = new JTextField("Dessert"), c);

        // row 2
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(t02 = new JTextField("Beth"), c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(t12 = new JTextField("25"), c);

        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(t22 = new JTextField("38"), c);

        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(t32 = new JTextField("28"), c);

        // row 3
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(t03 = new JTextField("Jon"), c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(t13 = new JTextField("35"), c);

        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(t23 = new JTextField("29"), c);

        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(t33 = new JTextField("37"), c);

        // row 4
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(t04 = new JTextField("Lupe"), c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(t14 = new JTextField("20"), c);

        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(t24 = new JTextField("31"), c);

        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(t34 = new JTextField("39"), c);

        // row 5
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 5;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(t05 = new JTextField("Amy"), c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 5;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(t15 = new JTextField("40"), c);

        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 5;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(t25 = new JTextField("32"), c);

        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 5;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(t35 = new JTextField("36"), c);

        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TableGrid());
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show me ways to make this GUI look more sleek and professional?

Comment: @wolowiz68: A [JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) would probably look better, although you're limited to column headings.  You would have to put the title in a JLabel.  If you want to stick with the JTextFields, using a horizontal fill would even out the JTextFields.